# ClassCastException in webclient

Tags: java, webclient

I am using web client for getting page source. First time i am getting page source. After i use the same object for getting page source for different URL it's showing an Exception like:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.UnexpectedPage cannot be cast to com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage
```

This is the code which i am using.

```
HtmlPage firstPage = webClient.getPage("firsturl");
HtmlPage downloadPage = null;
        try {
            webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            downloadPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("secondurl");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying it quite clearly, Your code is doing:

```
downloadPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("secondurl");
```

so you assume you are getting an object of type `HtmlPage`, but you are actually getting an object of type 
`UnexpectedPage`.

You should add a check of instanceof:

```
If (webClient.getPage("secondurl") instanceof HtmlPage){
downloadPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("secondurl");
}
else{
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume (without knowing the library too well any more) that UnexpectedPage is a subtype of HtmlPage (if it isn't - that's the reason for your problem).

In this case you probably have these classes twice on the classpath. While the "name" of the class HtmlPage looks like the legitimate superclass, the classloader has access to two classes of the same name and loaded "the other" one first.

Check (double-check) for HtmlUnit classes appearing twice on your classpath.